# Rackspace + Google Cloud SQL

Tags: connection, google-cloud-sql, rackspace-cloud

Im getting "ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0" trying to connect from rackspace to Google Cloud SQL. It just started to issue this error on 2014-07-14 arround 15:49.

My Rackspace server ip is authorized on Cloud SQL admin interface, also, I'm connecting from other ips outside from Rackspace infra and its all seems ok.

Another interesting point is that I don't receive the error every time, just arround 2/3 of the times.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a potentially known issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-announce/WIQ2g13aItI

"We are currently experiencing an issue with Google Cloud SQL and some users are experiencing loss of connectivity from Google Compute Engine to Cloud SQL instances. For everyone who is affected, we apologize for any inconvenience you may be experiencing."

You're not on Compute Engine, but it's possible that you're getting hit by the same problem.